# Dev story public links now show your screen name instead of your real name; something I can rely on, or a bug?

Tags: support, developer-story

In Story Preferences, you can get a public link to your Story or CV, and are told "Real name will be shown". However, I see SO recently changed public links to use your screen name instead. I'm generally positive about this change - for privacy reasons, I want to remain pseudonymous to everyone except potential employers - but I'd like to know if it's a change I can rely on, or a bug that will be fixed. If the latter, I'd appreciate if I could also get greater control on when exactly my real name and my pseudonym (= GitHub handle = personal site name) will appear together.

Answer (score 1):

I'm concerned and perplexed about this too. I just updated my developer story to start preparing for a job search, but I'm not ready to give my real name out to employers just yet as I am employed and I don't want my employer to see that right now.

Because I didn't know how my personal name was used and didn't want that out of my control, I set it to "anonymous for now" or something like that, but now I don't see that information anywhere or a way to edit it, and that doesn't follow the norm either, and no way to anticipate that I couldn't change it to my real name later.

Control of personal privacy is very important to people and critical so if we are to participate in the job market through this site we need some say/access/control over what is actually published, and exchanged, particularly with regard to personal details.